# How to leverage Resharper's "navigate to controller method" feature

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, resharper, redirecttoaction

Resharper 6 has a very nice new feature: If I write RedirectToAction or Html.Action anywhere in a MVC3 project, it get's underlined and using ctrl-click I can navigate there. It also notifies me if no such action exists.
**However**, I have a helper method in my BaseController, which takes an additional parameter (to put into TempData), and then calls a RedirectToAction. Unfortunately, **Resharper doesn't acknowledge these strings as controller and method names**, and doesn't underline.

I'm using the same parameter naming convention as MVC, my return type is the same, but still no. Is it possible that MVC's methods are hard-coded into Resharper? *Is there a way to make it work on my method too?*

[image: Image included for clarity]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by using ReSharper's code annotation attributes.

First, go to ReSharper->Options->Code Annotations, copy attributes' implementation to clipboard and add them to your project.

Then, mark parameters of your methods with necessary attributes. For example, parameter containing action string, mark with `AspMvcActionAttribute`; controller - with `AspMvcControllerAttribute` and etc.

Comment: so far great. If I have an overload that only takes the errorstring, and it redirects to CurrentController/Index, what do I need to add to the method to underline that too?

Comment: Mark with both attributes (AspMvcController and AspMvcAction) method itself.

Comment: how? I've put  [AspMvcAction("Index"), AspMvcController] above the method, now Resharper says cannot navigate to action "IssueController" where IssueController is the controller I'm trying to use it in. It should go to Issue/Index

Comment: TDaver, appears it is not working properly with controller/actions attributes on method level - only with views attributes.

Comment: Instead of copying the code annotations code into your project, you can also install the package via Nuget: install-package JetBrains.Annotations